# Cannot Evaluate Expression

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a method which got 6577 lines of code names getdata() without any parameters, this method is being called from Page_load event, before entering in this method my debugger works fine i.e. I can add watch string variables, DataTable etc.

But when I step into getdata() method I am unable to add watch DataTables but still able to add watch other variables like string, int etc.

When I try to Add watch DataTable I get the following error

"Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized"

I searched on Internet and found that this might be due to Method Signature being too long. But in my case there are no Parameters.

What interesting is that if I comment 6000 lines in this method than I'm able to Add watch DataTables.

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to debug the release build?

Comment: No it is not release mode, debug mode is selected

Comment: Can you show the signature of the method, what does it return?

Comment: Here is the Signature , it doesn't return anything
void getdata()

Comment: Does it declare a lot of lambdas or anonymous methods inside?

Comment: There are many String , int, ArrayList, DataTable variables being initialized in this method,

Comment: Did you try pressing F10? http://stackoverflow.com/a/362335/4136325

Comment: Pressing F10 will take me to next line even than Im not able to Add watch but if I Press F11 which will take me into another method which is being called inside that method I can add watch DataTable

Comment: Do you have a large amount of local variables?  The CLR won't allow function evaluation if the current method is using too much stack space.

Comment: Yes I have but they are inside different if else conditions